# tried a lot but can't solve it in python 2.7.14

Tags: python, python-2.x, pyautogui

Working on a project [Control your Computer with Hand Gestures using Arduino](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/control-your-computer-with-hand-gestures#comment-29952)
but `pyautogui` is not supporting me.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pyautogui

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    import pyscreeze
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator (__init__.py, line 168)
>>>
```

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the 2.7 version.  See https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/issues/46.  Move on to Python 3.

Comment: @cdarke thank you so much. It's solved